# Pass generic type and use type property

Tags: generics, typescript

I'm quite new in TypeScript and despite that I've red docs I simply cannot achieve what I want with generics.

I want to do something like that:

```
declare interface ObjectInterface {
    someKey: string
}

const model: SomeInterface = createModel<ObjectInterface>(someArrayOfObjects);
```

and here is `createModel` method:

```
private createModel<T>(someArray: T[]): SomeInterface {
    const model: SomeInterface = (...someCode...);

    someArray.forEach((obj: T) => { model.doSomething(obj.someKey) });

    return model;
}
```

and TypeScript throws me an error: `error TS2339: Property 'someKey' does not exist on type 'T'.`

Here is the part which I don't get it. If `ObjectInterface` has `someKey` and is passed as generic type to `createModel` then why `obj` doesn't 'see' it as it's property?

If there is an answer in google then please give me a hint what keys should I search? ;)

Comment: You need to add a constraint on `T`: `createModel<T extends ObjectInterface>(someArray: T[]): SomeInterface { ... }`

Comment: Thanks, I found this also in docs but somehow I was thinking that it is only for things that are not specifically set on interface like `.length`. I was thinking that if I will pass ObjectInterface then TS will just know that there is that key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, within your `createModel<T>` function, `T` can be literally anything (`any`). Because of this, it cannot be guaranteed at compile-time that a variable of type `T` actually contains a property `someKey`. For example, consider someone calling your method with `createModel<SomeOtherInterface>(...)` with `SomeOtherInterface` not having a `someKey` property, or even with `createModel<string>(...)`.

You can enforce that any type parameter used for `T` needs to be a subtype of `ObjectInterface` by formulating a *constaint*  on that type parameter:

```
createModel<T extends ObjectInterface>(someArray: T[]): SomeInterface {
    // ...
}
```

Have a look at [the respective section of the documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) for more information on generics.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Under my question Lee wrote the same suggestion so I will just copy paste what I wrote there: I found this also in docs but somehow I was thinking that it is only for things that are not specifically set on interface like `.length`. I was thinking that if I will pass ObjectInterface then TS will just know that there is that key.